# Django: queryset.latest('attr').attr performance penalty

Tags: django, django-queryset

For some reason this line:

```
val = queryset.latest('attr').attr
```

works significantly slower than:

```
obj = queryset.latest('attr')
val = obj.attr
```

in an ajax view I'm working on. This behavior is surprisingly consistent and I'm wondering if there's any bad magic behind the scenes that causes this performance penalty (benchmarked ~20s instead of ~2s)

Setup: Django 1.4.3, Python 2.7.3, debugging via PyCharm on Windows
Although I think this also occurs on my Heroku setup though

Answer (score 0):

If you only access the `attr` once, then there shouldn't be any noticeable difference beween the two queries.

However, note that the following code

```
val = queryset.latest('attr').attr
val = queryset.latest('attr').attr
val = queryset.latest('attr').attr
```

will fetch the object from the database each time, resulting in 3 database queries. If you assign queryset.latest('attr') to an object, there will only be 1 database query.

```
obj = queryset.latest('attr')
val = obj.attr
val = obj.attr
val = obj.attr
```

Comment: I access only once, there is a difference. I can't explain it.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions.